# how to have correctly multiple variables in same shared memory segment

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am trying to have 2 integers in the same memory segment. My code is the following:

```
int main()
{
  int *a;
  int *b;
  int id;
  id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,10,0666);
  a = (int *) shmat(id, (void*)0, 0);
  b = (int *) shmat(id, (void*)0, 0);
  *a = 5;
  *b = 10;
  printf("%d\n",*a);
  printf("%d\n",*b);
}
```

This prints 10 twice. Could anyone explain me why does this happen and how to solve it?

Extra question: If I had char * instead of int would it be necessary to do malloc(sizeof(char)*10) or the shmat call does the job in some way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: refer [this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html), all the IPC examples are given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you always want to use `malloc` rather than shared memory when possible.
Even when doing IPC, simple pipes are typically more efficient.

Back, to your question, here are some explanations to your code

```
int main()
{
  int *a;
  int *b;
  int id;

  /* 'shmget' creates a shared memory segments of size 10,
     basically reserving 10 bytes of RAM/Swap. This memory is not 
     accessible in your virtual memory yet */   
  id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,10,0666);

  /* `shmat` maps the shared memory from above and makes it accessible in
     your virtual memory. `a` points to the beginning of the memory segment */ 
  a = (int *) shmat(id, (void*)0, 0);

  /* Here we map the same shared memory again into a different place in the
     virtual memory. But even if `a` and `b` points to different memory
     addresses, those addresses are backed by the same segment in RAM/Swap */  
  b = (int *) shmat(id, (void*)0, 0);

  *a = 5;
  *b = 10; /* because `*a` and `*b` are backed by the same RAM/Swap, */ 
           /* this will allso overwrite `*a`                        */

  printf("%d\n",*a);
  printf("%d\n",*b);
}
```

To solve this, you have basically two options. Either have two shared memory segments, one for `a` and one for `b`. Or you make one segment large enough to hold for both `a` and `b` to point to different places in the segment:

First solution:

```
/* This uses two segments */
int *a;
int *b;
int id1;
int id2;
id1 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0666);
id2 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0666);
a = (int *) shmat(id1, (void*)0, 0);
b = (int *) shmat(id2, (void*)0, 0);
```

Second solution:

```
/* This uses one segments */
int *a;
int *b;
int id;
/* Allocate enough memory for 2 int */
id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2*sizeof(int), 0666);
/* Map that memory into virtual memory space */
a = (int *) shmat(id, (void*)0, 0);
/* `a` points to the first int in a sequence of 2 ints, let `b` point to 
   the next one. */
b = a + 1;
```

As always, this code has omitted error checking for brevity. Adding error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

To the extra question, neither `malloc` or any shared memory function cares about what you are going to store in the allocated memory. They just give you a sequence of `char`. It is your job to calculate how many `char` you need. (and btw `sizeof(char)` is always 1)

Comment: Naturally this wont probably make any sense unless you get a basic understanding of virtual memory first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if a was integer and b was character? Would the second solution work?

Comment: @PanD22, sure mixing datatypes in an allocated memory is totally possible. You just have to calculate the offsets correctly. The easiest way is to put an `int` and a `char` in a struct, and allocate enough memory for that struct.